# Rails get only array elements from another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got result from below query:

`query`

```
class SyncResult
  def self.query(products)
    Imports::Product
      .order(:last_sync_at)
      .pluck(:id, :name, :code, :sync_result, :last_sync_at)
      .map do |id, name, code, result, last_sync_at|
        {
          id: id,
          name: name,
          code: code,
          result: result,
          last_sync_at: last_sync_at
        }
      end
  end
end
```

`query result`

```
=> [{:id=>"611ea9a7392ab50013cf4713", :name=>"2-Tone Hoodie", :code=>"SS22CH013", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
     {:id=>"60ec84062f25d400150b351c", :name=>"5-Pocket Denim", :code=>"SS22WP014", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
     {:id=>"61966dc83e81dd001731ccd7", :name=>"Zip Shirt Jacket", :code=>"FW22WT001", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
     {:id=>"61d5cab6b41408001b0e9376", :name=>"Yankees Satin Varsity Jacket", :code=>"FW22WJ021", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil}]
```

`products = ['SS22CH013', 'FW22WJ021']`

Now I want to get only these array hash element which incudes code from `products` array.
End result should be:

```
=> [{:id=>"611ea9a7392ab50013cf4713", :name=>"2-Tone Hoodie", :code=>"SS22CH013", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
{:id=>"61d5cab6b41408001b0e9376", :name=>"Yankees Satin Varsity Jacket", :code=>"FW22WJ021", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the expected result in following ways.

1. Updating query to fetch Products for given codes

   ```rb
   products = ['SS22CH013', 'FW22WJ021']

   Imports::Product
     .where(code: products)
     .order(:last_sync_at)
     .pluck(:id, :name, :code, :sync_result, :last_sync_at)
     .map do |id, name, code, result, last_sync_at|
       {
         id: id,
         name: name,
         code: code,
         result: result,
         last_sync_at: last_sync_at
       }
   ```
2. Updating query to fetch Products for given codes(without pluck)

   ```rb
   products = ['SS22CH013', 'FW22WJ021']

   Imports::Product
     .where(code: products)
     .order(:last_sync_at)
     .select(:id, :name, :code, :sync_result, :last_sync_at)
     .map(&:attributes)
   ```
3. using `select` on query result

   ```rb
    query_result = [{:id=>"611ea9a7392ab50013cf4713", :name=>"2-Tone Hoodie", :code=>"SS22CH013", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
    {:id=>"60ec84062f25d400150b351c", :name=>"5-Pocket Denim", :code=>"SS22WP014", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
    {:id=>"61966dc83e81dd001731ccd7", :name=>"Zip Shirt Jacket", :code=>"FW22WT001", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
    {:id=>"61d5cab6b41408001b0e9376", :name=>"Yankees Satin Varsity Jacket", :code=>"FW22WJ021", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil}]

    products = ['SS22CH013', 'FW22WJ021']
    query_result.select{ |product| products.include?(product[:code]) }
   ```